# comparing tuples/dictionary python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set, list-comprehension

I have a txt file as shown below this paragraph. I'm writing a simple program (although not for me apparently) that takes a date at the command line (via sys.argv[1]) and if the date 
is older than the date below the file then file gets downloaded. Basically, I compare dates and if date next to file is newer then the file downloads automatically probably using wget. I'm wondering how I should structure this type of comparison? Should I make a dictionary with file and date {63337454-part002.csv.gz : 2014-01-28}, sets, or a list of tuples? I can create either of those its the comparison I'm really struggling with. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks so much.

63337454-part002.csv.gz

2014-01-28

63337454-part001.csv.gz

2014-01-28

63193394-part002.csv.gz

2014-01-25

63193394-part001.csv.gz

2014-01-25

63147949-part002.csv.gz

2014-01-24

63147949-part001.csv.gz

2014-01-24

Comment: Are your dates always written as `yyyy-mm-dd`? Because that would be great.

Comment: yes dates are in that format.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that filenames are unique, and dates are not, I would make a dictionary of filenames to dates and use a list comprehension along the lines of

```
[f for (f, d) in files_dict.items() if d < reference_date]
```

(note that this is just an example of how I'd go about it, not intended to be a complete solution)

If you parse the date to a datetime.date and use that as the value (rather than the raw string) the comparison will be easier to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a truly massive number of these 1-to-1 relationships, you should be using a proper database.

Otherwise a sequence of 2-tuples will suffice.  For extra credit you can sort them by date (ascending) so that you can take everything-up-to target date.

```
s = """
#that string you posted
"""

li = [x for x in s.splitlines() if x]

tups = [tuple(li[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(li), 2)]

tups.sort(key=lambda x: x[1]) #or key=operator.itemgetter(1)

tups
Out[44]: 
[('63147949-part002.csv.gz', '2014-01-24'),
 ('63147949-part001.csv.gz', '2014-01-24'),
 ('63193394-part002.csv.gz', '2014-01-25'),
 ('63193394-part001.csv.gz', '2014-01-25'),
 ('63337454-part002.csv.gz', '2014-01-28'),
 ('63337454-part001.csv.gz', '2014-01-28')]

from itertools import takewhile

list(takewhile(lambda x: x[1] < '2014-01-28',tups))
Out[47]: 
[('63147949-part002.csv.gz', '2014-01-24'),
 ('63147949-part001.csv.gz', '2014-01-24'),
 ('63193394-part002.csv.gz', '2014-01-25'),
 ('63193394-part001.csv.gz', '2014-01-25')]
```

Some notes on the above:

- You can safely compare date strings lexicographically because the dates are in [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format
- You can save a little bit of time if you're doing this operation multiple times by first sorting by date.  Then you know that once you pass your target date, you don't need to look any more.

Comment: damn homey thanks. i need to work on sorting especially understanding different sorting algorithms.